# Why $\mathbb Q$ has not the supremum property?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Why $\mathbb Q$ has not the supremum property ? i.e. why an upper bounded doesn't necessarily have a supremum ? As a hint, I have to consider $A=\{x\in\mathbb Q\mid x^2\leq 2\}$. I tried by contradiction : suppose there is $k$ s.t. $k=\sup A$. How can I get a contradiction ?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$k\in\mathbb Q$, so in particular $k\neq \sqrt 2$. Now, if $k<\sqrt 2$ we have a contradiction with density of $\mathbb Q$ in $\mathbb R$. Same if $k>\sqrt 2$. The claim follows.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**  $\Bbb Q$ is not *complete*.

So take $A$ to be a sequence of rationals converging to $\sqrt2$ from below. The only candidate for $\operatorname {sup}A$ is $\sqrt2$, which is not in $\Bbb Q$.